# What does this quote from "The adventures of Sherlock Holmes" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors, literature

> A man should keep his little brain attic stocked with all the furniture that he is likely to use, and the rest he can put away in the lumber-room of his library, where he can get it if he wants it.

*The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes*, Arthur Conan Doyle

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to focus on practically useful kinds of knowledge while everything else can be looked up in books when necessary. If I remember it well, Holmes wasn't even sure if the earth goes round the sun and found that knowledge useless for his practice.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time! :) and thank you for your help! :)